# Screen Does not show after being activated - Caliburn.Micro WPF

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have this parent Screen that should `show/hide` other screen based on the `ListViewItem` that has been click.

```
  public class TabViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    private BPLOViewModel _bPLOViewModel;
    private BusinessInfoViewModel _businessInfoViewModel;
    public TabViewModel(BPLOViewModel bPLOViewModel, BusinessInfoViewModel businessInfoViewModel)
    {
        _bPLOViewModel = bPLOViewModel;
        _businessInfoViewModel = businessInfoViewModel;
        ActivateItem(_bPLOViewModel);

    }

    public void GeneralInfo()
    {
        DeactivateItem(ActiveItem,true);
        ActivateItem(_businessInfoViewModel);
    }

    public void Bplo()
    {
        DeactivateItem(ActiveItem, true);
        ActivateItem(_bPLOViewModel);
    }
}
```

Code in xaml:

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <ListView x:Name="GeneralInfo" Foreground="White" FontSize="15">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Store" Margin="15" Foreground="Orange"/>
                <TextBlock Text="General Info" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ListView>
        <ListView  x:Name="Bplo" Foreground="White" FontSize="15">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Store" Margin="15" Foreground="Orange"/>
                <TextBlock Text="BPLO" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ListView>
   </StackPanel>
```

It only triggers one time then after that it doesnt work.

I tried using  `ActivateItem(IoC.Get<[ViewModelName]>());` but the event wont fire either

Comment: Could you put a sample on github that shows the issue?  I will look at it

Answer (score 0):

When you are deactivating the view model, you are closing the view model as well as deactivating it.

```
    DeactivateItem(ActiveItem,true);
```

If you call this instead, you won't close the view model when you deactivate it.

```
    DeactivateItem(ActiveItem,false);
```

That would explain why things work the first time, but then don't work after that.